# Ember.js attempting to get a weird script

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, get, request

I'm very new to the whole concept of a web application framework, and I started out with ember.js last night. I've followed their video tutorial on getting started and I have this problem.

Ember.js is attempting to make a GET request to access some very weird file. Here is my files and the error. The code works perfectly apart from ember making a request and getting a forbidden 403 error (due to apache blocking it for having incorrect characters)

```
<!-- An extract of my index.html -->

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="shots">
        {{#each}}
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            <h6>Shot ID: {{id}}</h6>
            <hr />
            <p>Published on the {{pubDate}} by {{author.name}}</p>
            <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{description}}" />
            <p>{{description}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

And then this is my JavaScript:

```
// core.js
Master = Ember.Application.create();

Master.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('home');
    this.resource('shots');
});

Master.ShotsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return shots;
    }
});    
var shots = [{
    id: '1',
    title: "It Works!",
    author: { name: "Luke Shiels", user: "0001"},
    image: "assets/img/0001.png",
    pubDate: new Date('26-11-2000'),
    description: "A new shot, lol!"
}, {
    id: '2',
    title: "It also Works!",
    author: { name: "Luke Shiels", user: "0001"},
    image: "assets/img/0001.png",
    pubDate: new Date('27-11-2000'),
    description: "Another shot, lol!"   
}];
```

I get the following 'errors':
`http://i.imgur.com/fRLkaFQ.png` (Sorry, don't have enough rep to post images)

Comment: share the pic with error expanded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how Handlebars handles DOM updates you can't just add attributes inside of an HTML tag like you've done with the image.

```
<img src="{{image}}" alt="{{description}}" />
```

If you look at the generated HTML it will look something like:

```
<img src="<script id='metamorph-1-start'>someh</script>">
```

You need to look at the `{{bindAttr}}` helper instead.

```
<img {{bindAttr src="image" alt="description"}}/>
```